# How to cancel a deletion after pressing 'd' in normal mode?

Tags: normal-mode

If I'm in normal mode and I accidentally press <kbd>d</kbd> vim will then wait for a motion to choose what to delete. Is their a motion or cancel command to not delete anything? Is the only option to delete something and then undo it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any command can be interrupted either by <kbd>ESC</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

Just hit the 'ESC' key. It will cancel whatever command you are in the middle of typing.